# How to dynamically require images in React (using GET request to fetch images)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, require

I have a profile picture for each user.

I fetch these pictures `paths` from my database column.

Then store them in `state`.

`const PROFILE_INFO = this.state.PROFILE_INFO;
<img src={require(PROFILE_INFO.ImageURL)} /> // ImageURL /stored_images/b234afaf-ccea-599f-9b3b-3cbf2d669b21.jpg`

The problem is this doesn't work because `require()` only accepts `STATIC` paths.

[image]

[image]

This happens when i use

`<img src={`../..${PROFILE_INFO.ImageURL}`} />`

Comment: No, it happens when you use `require` with something that isn't a string that can be resolved for bundling purposes. You can't use `require(someVariable)` with webpack, because `someVariable` could be anything and so webpack can't pack that and errors out. With that said, it looks like you already have the URL as `PROFILE_INFO.ImageURL` so why not just use that directly? (also, on a JS naming convention, constants are all caps, classes start with a capital letter, functions/vars start with lowercase. Always good to follow that convention)

Comment: I can't use it DIRECTLY because its A STATIC url.. its a unique image name for each profile.

Comment: Okay but why are you using `require` then? Because that's the node.js instruction for loading a node module/package. If it's just a string, don't use `require`, as per charlietfl's answer. Using `require` is absolutely _not_ how you load an image into a react app. If your JSX is for DOM/HTML target, template the `src` attribute as a string. The end. Don't *ever* bundle those in, that would be insane. You'd have to rebuild the entire app bundle every time you updated an image source. That'd be beyond crazy.

Comment: Trying to insert images with just strings DOES NOT work. i get a broken-image-icon

Comment: cool: and what _error_ do you get? Open dev tools, look at the console, look at the network tab, and determine where in your string you had your typo(s). "It does not work" is not a problem: it _always_ works, exactly the way it should. You're seeing "it does not do what I expected", so apply standard procedure and determine what it does, so that you have the information you need to determine how to fix it.

Comment: I EDITED THE POST. i do not have typos and the path is perfectly right. anyways i found a way to make it work but only when the `stored_images` folder are in the same folder as the `html` file. which is a huge problem.

Comment: There's no need to yell: if you edited the post, I don't see it. The error you show uses `require`, so that's not the error you get when you use `<img src={../..${PROFILE_INFO.ImageURL}} />`, to which the follow-up question is: "why are you adding those `../..`?" because presumably you noticed your browser trying to load the wrong URL, so what did you see in the console/network tab? E.g. what proof from your browser do you have that you need anything more than just `<img src={PROFILE_INFO.ImageURL} />`, and can you show that in your post?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `require()`. All you should need  is the url string

```
<img src={PROFILE_INFO.ImageURL} />
```

Comment: In React that's the way you insert images.

Comment: define *"doesn't work"*. Are images on same domain as page? What do you see in browser dev tools network?

Comment: Images are physically stored in a folder located very closely. i edited the post for what happens when using your solution.

Comment: if i use `../../stored_images/b234afaf-ccea-599f-9b3b-3cbf2d669b21.jpg` in `src` it works while thats literally whats stored in my `object` `PROFILE_DETAILS`.
It's a common problem but i cannot find any solutions what so ever.